# Usage de "copie conforme" (courriel)

Tags: usage, locutions, correspondance

> Je mets M. X en copie conforme sur le courriel.

La locution *copie conforme* est-elle répandu et compréhensible ?

**EDIT**

La locution se rencontre aussi ici : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/copie_conforme

> (Internet) Envoi simultané à une autre personne que le destinataire
>   principal d’un courriel. Mettre quelqu’un en copie conforme sur un
>   courriel.

Comment: Votre interlocuteur serait-il québecois ? Je me demande si ce n'est pas un usage du français canadien, en français européen, je ne pense avoir jamais lu ou entendu que "copie carbone" pour le "cc" des e-mails.

Comment: @Greg  Du coup, c'est moi qu l'a utilise:-)! Je l'ai trouvé sur wiki et j'ai pensé pouvoir l'utiliser. Puis, je me suis posé la question si les personnes qui ont reçu le message aient compris...Voici donc la question:-)!

Comment: Alors je te conseille de simplement utiliser "mettre en copie", qui sera compris de tous et ne suscitera pas d'interrogations.

Comment: [_Copie confome_](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26545179) ; autres détails [ici](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=COPIE+CONFORME&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) et [là](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=copie+conforme&i=1&cur=1&nmbr=&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) et [encore](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/juridi-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=copie+conforme&i=&lettr=indx_catlog_l&cur=1&nmbr=&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) et [aussi](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2105).

Comment: Merci - remarquez que ce sont toutes des sources canadiennes, ce qui renforce mon hypothèse qu'il s'agit d'un usage propre au Québec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non, *copie conforme* n'est pas utilisé (en Europe au moins)<sup>1</sup> dans le contexte de la messagerie électronique. L'expression en usage est ***mettre quelqu'un en copie***, qui correspond à l'anglais *cc* pour *carbon-copy*. Il existe aussi *cci* (copie-carbone/conforme invisible) pour bcc (*blind carbon-copy*).

> Je met M. X en copie de ce courrier électronique.

On dit *copie conforme* quand il s'agit de la copie d'un document qui a été certifiée par une autorité, ou au sens figuré pour souligner la ressemblance entre deux objets ou personnes.

Comme Greg en commentaire, je n'ai jamais rencontré l'utilisation décrite dans Wikipédia, et serais surpris si quelqu'un m'écrivait *je met Untel en copie conforme*, comme d'ailleurs *je met Untel en copie carbone* serait incongru.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Toutes les sources de l'utilisation de *copie conforme* dans un contexte de messagerie électronique semblent être relatives au Québec.</sub>

Comment: Merci. The initials CC (mails) stand for what in French? https://www.programme-tv.net/news/buzz/59175-que-veut-dire-cc-et-cci/

Comment: By the way, (Internet) Envoi simultané à une autre personne que le destinataire principal d’un courriel.
Mettre quelqu’un en copie conforme sur un courriel. (wiki: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/copie_conforme)

Comment: I was typing an answer very similar to jiliagre's, and then I saw your link to the wiktionary artcile, which really surprises me, I had never seen the usage of *copie conforme* for an e-mail cc...I have found multiple occurences  of it with some quick googling., but looking at the origin of those  I wonder if this is not rather a French Canadian usage. ex: http://www.copie-conforme.cc/fr/qu-est-ce-que-cc/

Answer (score 1):

Il existe deux sens de ce terme ; on les trouve au lien [suivant](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/copie-conforme/) ;

> sens 1 Chose qui est semblable à une autre.
>  
>   Sens 2 Copie qui est certifiée être conforme à l'original.

« Copie conforme » peut donc être synonyme de « copie certifiée conforme ».

Le lien suivant donne des informations sur la légalité en ce qui concerne les copies certifiées conformes ([légalité](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1412)).

Answer (score 1):

Avant le courriel, dans certaines organisations, les notes diffusées avaient deux listes de destinataires: Les destinataires "pour action" et ceux "pour information". Il existe des règles d'usage de la messagerie électronique qui transposent ce mode de fonctionnement avec les champs "To:" et "Cc:" respectivement.